# How can I fix the position of an element when it reaches a certain location in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

Forgive me if this question is too silly. I am making a webpage on which I will have a header that consists of two parts(upper and lower). When I scroll down the page, I want the lower part of the header still stay here. How can I implement this? I plan to write a javascript to handle this - once the lower part reach (0, 0), its position is changed to absolute from relative. I think this is gonna work but I am just wondering if there exist a better and simple way to do it.
Thank you!

Comment: Depending on which browsers/versions you want to support, [`position: fixed`](http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position) might work for you.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - While position fixed is what he needs, don't forget that it still requires javascript. He doesn't want the lower part of the header to stay there hanging in the middle of the screen.

Comment: @JosephSilber - Keep in mind if that were a full-blown answer, it wouldn't be a comment. `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/JLETx/4/

UPDATE: fixed the "jumping content"

**HTML**

```
<div id="topHeader">top header</div>
<div id="bottomHeader">bottome header</div>
<div id="extremelyLongContent"> long content here </div>
```

**JS**

```
var initial = $('#bottomHeader').offset();

$(document).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > initial.top) {
    $('#bottomHeader').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('#topHeader').css('margin-bottom', initial.top+'px');
    $('#bottomHeader').css('top','0'); 
}
else {
    $('#bottomHeader').css('position', 'static');
    $('#topHeader').css('margin-bottom', 0);
}

});
```

**CSS**

```
body{
position:relative;
}

#topHeader{
background:red;
height:100px;
}
#bottomHeader{
background:blue;
height:100px;
width:100%;
}

#extremelyLongContent{
background:green;
height:1000px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/). Sounds like it could come in handy for you.